# add array to json encoded array from PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, arrays, json, fetch

I am returning all the product category from db and encoding to json, this works fine, only that I would like to modify the value of the image_url returned and add the http:// at the back since it is not in the db value.

```
$catlist = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `categories`");
$catlist->execute();
while($Categories = $catlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$newArr[] = $Categories;
}
echo json_encode(array_values($newArr));
```

The data returned is thus:

```
[{"id":"81","name":"My Cate", "image_url":"ginger.gif" },{"id":"82","name":"Jane Doe", "image_url": "offf.gif"}]
```

So my aim is to concatenate the http://x.com/ to the image url object data.

Comment: do it before encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your array before to add it in your array :

```
$catlist = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `categories`");
$catlist->execute();
while($Categories = $catlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $Categories['image_url'] = "http://x.com/".$Categories['image_url']; //<- Add this line
    $newArr[] = $Categories;
} 
echo json_encode(array_values($newArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do the concatenation in your query using [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Then you won't need to loop over the result in PHP, you can just `fetchAll`, `json_encode`, and output.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, CONCAT('http://', image_url) AS image_url FROM categories";
$catlist = $pdo->query($sql);
$categories = $catlist->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the loop and `$newArray` if use `fetchall()` it will return your results as array, you can achieve what u want with two lines

```
<?php
$catlist = $pdo->query("SELECT id,name,CONCAT('http://x.com/', image_url) AS imgURl FROM `categories`")->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode(array_values($catlist));

?>
```